# Android 2.1 SDK is not available in the list of available packages

Tags: android, sdk, version

As long as I know there's only one way to install SDK versions - through the Android SDK and AVD Manager. I want to install SDK Platform Android 2.1 but it's not in the list of available packages, there are only Android SDK Tools revision 15 and Android SDK PLatform-tools revision 9.
Where can I get it - 2.1 revision 7?

Comment: which version of sdk you are currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download latest sdk version 15 ..android-sdk_r15-windows.zip and open SDK Manager where u can see the version of Android for download[image]